# Paypal sandbox. Unable to confirming bank account on test accounts and buy subscription

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I have created several preconfigured buyers test accounts over the week. Not a single one of the generated bank acount is confirmed. I have gone through the steps on the documentation to no avail. On some of them it errors on the continue button  under complete bank setup. It has a Deposit not sent on the Bank Account details above the button. Is says Sorry, an error occurred after you clicked the last link ... We are sorry, we are experiencing temporary difficulties. Please try again later. If this error occurred while making a payment, avoid duplicate payments by checking your Account Overview before resending a payment. I have cleared cookies and all cant move forward. On others I get to do the full submission and get to the end with a congratulations u have confirmed your account. However on the test account site it shows unconfirmed.

Also I cannot purchase a subscription at all with any of the accounts. It says cannot use this card please choose another source of funding.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this set-up. If you create a preconfigured personal buyer account from developer.paypal.com, the bank account should already be confirmed and verified. When you create a preconfigured account make sure to select "Buyer (use to represent your customer's experience)" and not "Buyer In-store (Use to represent your customer's experience with in-store checkout)". The In-store checkout does not give you a confirmed bank account.

When you create a In-store checkout Buyer Account, you will see the following error: Account Created Successfully but failed to add Credit Card and Bank.

- To test a merchant transaction, you must use a test Business Account
- To test a buyer transaction, you must use a Personal Account